# Identificar browser e sua versão

Tags: php, navegador-de-internet, cross-browser

Fiz varias pesquisas em diferentes sites mais ainda não achei uma solução definitiva e que de certo para todos os navegadores

Gostaria de saber como posso identificar o navegador e a versão dele usando PHP.

Por exemplo:

```
IE 9
CHROME 39
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

Comment: @gmsantos sim, já pesquisei muito sobre isso mas ainda não resolveu o problema.

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha eu ainda não entendi, se não é esse o seu problema, explica melhor o que você gostaria.... qual sua necessidade? Se for descobrir o navegador e a sua versão, essa é a única meneira.... tem algo mais que necessita?

Comment: Na documentação você encontra um código que faz o que você esta pedindo. Aqui ta o link do exemplo.                 [**Link**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#101125).

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio sim, gostaria de saber se alguém conhece alguma biblioteca que faça isso porque eu não manjo muito disso e pra fazer daria um trabalhão e to precisando fazer isso rápido

Comment: @SilvioAndorinha infelizmente não tem muita opção, se você quiser implementar algo assim na sua página, você tem que entender ao menos o minimo da coisa....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As informações sobre o browser do cliente se encontram na variável `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. Outros detalhes podem ser encontrados pela função [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php).

Ao se usar o `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` devemos notar que ele não está em uma linguagem de fácil entendimento, é preciso traduzir os [*User Agents*](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) para extrair essa informação.

Essa análise do user agent pode ser feita manualmente ou você pode utilizar de um package para te ajudar com isso. [Encontrei esse](https://github.com/sinergi/php-browser-detector) que é bem simples de usar.

Depois de instalado via composer:

```
composer require sinergi/browser-detector
```

basta fazer o seguinte:

```
use Sinergi\BrowserDetector\Browser;

$browser = new Browser();

if ($browser->getName() === $browser::CHROME) {
    echo 'Por favor, troque seu browser';
}
```

No próprio github temos a documentação de como usar esse package.

Answer (score 6):

Olá, eu optei por trabalhar da seguinte forma:

Criei uma função para verificar o navegador e o SO

```
private function VerificaNavegadorSO() {
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $bname = 'Unknown';
    $platform = 'Unknown';
    $version= "";

    if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'Linux';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'Mac';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'Windows';
    }


    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
        $ub = "MSIE";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
        $ub = "Firefox";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Google Chrome';
        $ub = "Chrome";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/AppleWebKit/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'AppleWebKit';
        $ub = "Opera";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Apple Safari';
        $ub = "Safari";
    }

    elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Netscape';
        $ub = "Netscape";
    }

    $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
    $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
    ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
    if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
    }


    $i = count($matches['browser']);
    if ($i != 1) {
        if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }
        else {
            $version= $matches['version'][1];
        }
    }
    else {
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }

    // check if we have a number
    if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

    $Browser = array(
            'userAgent' => $u_agent,
            'name'      => $bname,
            'version'   => $version,
            'platform'  => $platform,
            'pattern'    => $pattern
    );

    $navegador = "Navegador: " . $Browser['name'] . " " . $Browser['version'];
    $so = "SO: " . $Browser['platform'];

    /* Para finalizar coloquei aqui o meu insert para salvar na base de dados... Não fiz nada para mostrar em tela, pois só uso para fins de log do sistema  */
}
```

Na tabela ele salva "Navegador: Google Chrome 39.0.2171.95 - SO: Windows"

Comment: Perfeito! mas só tem um probleminha quando eu testo com o internet explorer ele da como variável UB undefied

Comment: Certo, mas você chegou a debugar pra ver em que ponto ocorre o erro? No sistema que implantei foi testado com o IE e funciona normalmente.

Comment: Sim debuguei, provavelmente ele não deve ter entrado no if quando verifica se é o IE

Comment: Aqui funcionou certinho a função da @Isabela Silvio

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio está dando esse erro http://s4.postimg.org/qyekb6ypp/Capturar.png

Comment: Silvio, Poste todo o seu código para ajudarmos (de preferência em novo tópico, visto que a solução foi apresentada e o problema agora é no teu código), pois se a função está ok pra eu e pro @MarceloBonifazio deve ser algo particular do teu código.

Answer (score 1):

Verifique o `User Agent` do navegador, e faça o tratamento de acordo com o resultado, você pode descobrir isso via **servidor** que recebeu a requisição de resposta, e na resposta já fazer o tratamento da página a ser renderizada, ou via **cliente**, e renderizar no próprio cliente.

**PHP**

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

**JS**

```
function UserAgente(){
      var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
      return ua;
}
```

Com isso fazer uma verificação de compatibilidade de acordo com a versão do navegador utilizado pelo cliente....

[Aqui você encontra uma lista completa de User Agents](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php)

Dai basta trabalhar com `Expressões Regulares`.
Identificando cada versão de um navegador pelo seu User Agent, isso é bem trabalhoso.
Lembrando que existem centenas de navegadores, cada um com dezenas e mais dezenas de versões diferentes.

Comment: Ele quer saber a versão do browser, não do php

Comment: Sim, eu entendi relendo a pergunta, inclusive tinha editado o tópico da pergunta dele pra ficar mais claro "Identificar browser e sua versão VIA PHP"