# Verificando navegador e versão com REGEX

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

Estou trabalhando em um sistema vb.net MVC e preciso detectar o navegador e versão.

Vou utilizar apenas Chrome, e IE9+.
Queria saber se consigo simplificar a estrutura da verificação utilizando Regex.

Abaixo o trecho que utilizo para fazer a verificação.

```
If (Not Request.Browser.ToString().ToLower().Contains("ie") And
        Not Request.Browser.ToString().ToLower().Contains("internet explorer") And
        Not Request.Browser.ToString().ToLower().Contains("chrome")) Then

        Return View("IncompativelAgent")
    Else
        If Not Request.Browser.ToString().ToLower().Contains("chrome") And Request.Browser.MajorVersion < 9 Then
            Return View("IncompativelAgent")
        End If
    End If
```

Acho muito deselegante da forma que está.

Comment: Você pode criar métodos pra isso e retornar TRUE ou FALSE.

Comment: a questão não é o encapsulamento e sim como fazer a verificação com regex para evitar esses IFs.

Comment: **Relacionado :** http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46871/identificar-browser-e-sua-vers%C3%A3o, só altera a linguagem.

Comment: Guilherme, não atende, o codifo chegou a ficar maior que o meu, acho que se nao for por regex, dificilmente conseguirei diminuir isso.

Comment: Meu algoritmo funciona e esta rodando de boa, eu queria simplificar esse trecho dos IFs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguindo [este link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx) para obtendo as informações :

#### `C#`

```
System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;

string pattern = @"ie|internet explorer|chrome";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(browser.Browser, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

if(matchs.Count == 0 And browser.Version < 9){
    Return View("IncompativelAgent");
}
```

#### `VB`

```
    Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("ie|internet explorer|chrome", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim match As Match = regex.Match(Request.Browser.Browser)
    If (Not match.Success Or (match.Success And Request.Browser.MajorVersion < 9)) Then
        Return View("IncompativelAgent")
    End If
```

#### Obs

Não sou conhecedor, montem com base em pesquisas.

#### Links

[How to: Detect Browser Types and Browser Capabilities in ASP.NET Web Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)
[Check Browser version and name (VB.net)](http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Request/CheckBrowserversionandnameVBnet.htm)
[VB.NET Regex.Match Function Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-vbnet)

Comment: Tem como traduzir para VB?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa vou ficar te devendo, como comentei ainda não conheço bem C# e VB, mas link a cima tem as informações em VB.

Comment: Eu tentei traduzir com um site aqui, também nao consegui... Mas vale a ajuda cara.

Comment: @PauloHDSousa Montei um VB, veja se esta ok, por favor

Comment: Guilgerme, perfeito!!! Fiz uma pequena alteracao para contemplar a regra porem era isso mesmo que eu queria, troquei 10 linhas por 5. Obrigado